# file path to wstring

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, wstring

I've been trying to convert a file path (eg. "D:\Data\set_1\got.bin" ) in my C++ program to wstring (since I want to open the file using `CreateFile()`. But I am having some difficulty. I am using the following version I gathered from one of the questions on stackoverflow:-

```
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buf2 = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf2, len);
    std::wstring r(buf2);
    delete[] buf2;
    return r;
}
```

It isn't working unfortunately. It works if I just pass in a file name without a full path. So my guess is that wstring conversion function I am using is unable to handle characters like `":"`,`"/"` etc. Is that the case? If so, how could I fix the above function to handle those things?

EDIT:

This is how the function has been used at the moment:-

```
string convLPCWSTRtoString(LPCWSTR wString)
{

    wstring tempWstring(wString);

    string tempString(tempWstring.begin(), tempWstring.end());

    cout << tempString;

    return tempString;

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::wstring stemp = s2ws(argv[1]);
    LPCWSTR test = stemp.c_str();

    convLPCWSTRtoString(test);


    testfile  = CreateFile(test, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);

    // Some reading and processing of the data here

return;
}
```

I call the function as

reader.exe "D:\Data\set_1\got.bin"

The print statement in the convLPCWSTRtoString() function prints couple of garbage characters. If I copy the exe over to the same folder, and then just give the argument "got.bin", it prints correctly and I can also read the file.

Comment: It handles those character fine.  Please post a [mcve] as the issue may be in the calling code.  Alternately just call `CreateFileA` with your narrow string.  Also instead of using `new` conciser using `std::vector<wchar_t>` for your temporary buffer.

Comment: The conversion itself is fine (though it can simplified by eliminating `+1` and `buf2` completely). Whatever problem you are having is related to how you are using the converted data. Please show that code.

Comment: If you're using a constant string as the path, check that escapes all \-characters correct. It will mess up your string if you don't. If you're reading it from a file or user input that's not the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, I added the information you requested to the post now! Perhaps I am making a mistake when converting back to string to print? But still, the file does not open correctly when it prints the garbage characters though.....

Comment: Could you try by using the path "D:/Data/set_1/got.bin" instead of "D:\Data\set_1\got.bin" (/ is a valid path separator in Windows)

Comment: @Clearer I tried that, but it gave the same result unfortunately!

Comment: @RichardCritten will try the CreateFileA and let you know if it works! That will hopefully fix it :)!

Comment: Hi @RichardCritten, I decided to go with the CreateFileA you mentioned and it works! :) Thank you for your help! If you post your same comment as an answer, I can then select it as the answer to my question as well.